# How to create a gap between adjacent arrows in connected Matplotlib Sankey subdiagrams

Tags: python, matplotlib, sankey-diagram

I have a Sankey diagram that has flows coming into and out of the main stream from both directions, but the flows going out of Sankey object N directly abut the flows going into Sankey object N+1.

I can't find any obvious candidates in the documentation for having something turn off "early". I can put in a dummy 0 flow, but that creates an unsightly arc. I've also tried changing the lengths of the output paths to limit the amount of text overlap, but then I'm still stuck with some text overlapping a diagram.

```py
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey

s = Sankey(scale=1./100, shoulder=0)

s.add(
    flows=[100, 20, -100, -20,], 
    orientations=[0,1,0,1, ],
    labels=["In", "LongInputName", None, "LongOutputName", ],
)

s.add(
    flows=[100, 30, -130],
    orientations=[0,1,0],
    labels=[None, "OtherLongInput", "Output"],
    prior=0,
    connect=(2,0),
)

_ = s.finish()
```

In this simplified example, the labels for LongOutput and OtherLongInput overlap, and the arrows "kiss" for some of their length.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with Sankey, but maybe adding a dummy, invisible, arrow in between the blue and orange could do the trick?

```
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey

s = Sankey(scale=1./100, shoulder=0)

s.add(
    flows=[100, 20, -100, -20,], 
    orientations=[0,1,0,1, ],
    labels=["In", "LongInputName", None, "LongOutputName", ],
)

s.add(
    flows = [100,-100],
    orientations = [0,0],
    labels=["",""],
    prior=0,
    connect=(2,0),
    fill=False,
    lw=0
    )

s.add(
    flows=[100, 30, -130],
    orientations=[0,1,0],
    labels=[None, "OtherLongInput", "Output"],
    prior=1,
    connect=(1,0),
)

_ = s.finish()
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a useful solution for somebody, but there's enough stages in the real diagram that I'm working on that adding enough whitespace to separate the labels makes the whole thing unwieldy in other ways.

Comment: However, what I can do is instead of having the dummy stage be blank, color it the same color as the previous stage using `s.diagrams[-1].patch.get_facecolor()`, which gets me most of the way there (with only slight visual hiccups around the edges).